# Asp.Net Maintain Scroll Position On PostBack Stopped Working in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome

I have developed a system in asp.net 4.0 and have MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack set to True at the top of all the vb.aspx pages. This ensures that all users return to the correct section of a page on a post back.

This has been working perfectly for 8 years, however about 3 months ago a user contacted me to state that this no longer worked and when the pages were posting back they were returning to the top of the page and not where the user was working.

Since then I have had another 5 members of the staff notify me that they are also experiencing the same issue. As a result I have to get these users to use Internet Explorer which is functioning correctly. However this is not ideal as our system are developed using chrome and optimised for this browser.

What’s more, I have another 95 members of staff who have the same setup and version latest of Chrome (40.0.2214.94 m) where this is not an issue and the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack is still functioning correctly.

I have tried moving the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack setting to the WebConfig file and also using JavaScript to remember the user’s position but these fixes still don’t work on the 6 machines.

Could someone please point me in the right direction to fix the issue that I am experiencing.

Kind Regards

Wayne Cornish